# Running a timed job and returning the values back to the parent form

Tags: powershell, jobs

I am still fairly new to the world of PowerShell and programming in general and I have undertaken a project to help me learn. I am trying to construct a function that compares a list of running processes against a list of those that should be running. The function will then return the object with 'On' or 'Off'. Below is what I currently have written and this works, but now I need to turn it into a job that runs every so many seconds.Please can anyone help? Any help is much appreciated.

```
function CheckRunningProcessesFunc
{
    $Processes = (Get-Variable InclusionList).Value.CheckedItems #List of proceese to check if they are on or off
    $RunningProcesses = Get-WMIObject Win32_Process -filter "Name='adc.exe' OR Name='optask.exe'" | select -expand path #current running processes
    foreach ($Process in $Processes)
    {
        $TimeNow = get-date -Format ‘HH:mm:ss’
        $Text = $TimeNow + " " + $Process
        if ($RunningProcesses -contains $Process)
        {
            $Result = $Text + ' is On'
            (Get-Variable ListBox).Value.Items.Add($Result)
        }
        else
        {
            $Result = $Text + ' is Off'
            (Get-Variable ListBox).Value.Items.Add($Result)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you want to process the result? Do you want to run it as a background task and store the result in a log file, or do you want to run it in a shell window until you cancel it manually?

Comment: @JonC 
Hi Jon,
I have a windows form that has a ListBox and I would like to add the result to the list box "(Get-Variable ListBox).Value.Items.Add($Result)". I also have a text Box called 'RefreshInputBox' that I would like the user to input a value (in seconds) for the refresh rate of the job. Any further assistance you can give will be much appreciated!
Many thanks, DogManDave

Answer (score 1):

From your comment it seems that you are using PowerShell to write a .NET GUI. That is a quite uncommon approach since PowerShell in essence is a scripting language. To maintain GUI responsiveness you always have to avoid blocking code and rely on techniques like event handling and callback functions. This isn't something that PowerShell is build to handle.

Since PS is built on the .NET framework there is nothing stopping you from instantiating the built-in objects like the Stopwatch class, but it will take a tremendous amount of work to get it to interact with PS to satisfaction.

My recommendation is, if you want to use WinForms then use C#. Then, if you want to leverage some of the strengths of PowerShell you have the entire System.Management.Automation namespace at your disposal.